# SQL Server 2008 automatically creates table when creating new database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. When I create a database by right clicking on the database folder and create new database, it creates the database with the name I given.

Additionally, the tables that are generated automatically are from a previously created table with different database name.

Comment: Look in the system `model` database - that's what's copied to create new DBs

Comment: by right clicking the database folder and selecting new database option

Comment: in model database where to look i cant understand you sorry

Comment: Some versions of SSMS don't show the tables nodes in object explorer for system databases - including `model`. You'll have to drop them with `USE model; DROP TABLE x, y, z` commands

Answer (score 8):

When a database is created, it is created based on the `model` database, as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186388.aspx):

> The model database is used as the template for all databases created
>   on an instance of SQL Server. Because tempdb is created every time SQL
>   Server is started, the model database must always exist on a SQL
>   Server system. The entire contents of the model database, including
>   database options, are copied to the new database.

So, you probably just need to remove the tables from `model`.

Comment: I was able to remove the view from the model database but i cant find any tables in there! what i am missing?

Comment: I cant able to find the tables in model database! what should i do to remove the tables from model and where to find them

Comment: @durai . . . There are a bunch of system tables that are created when you create a database.  You should edit the question and explain what the tables are.

Comment: The tables i am mentioning are user created tables